How do I deploy a CDK stack that relies on SSM parameters from a different stack?
I was told that using SSM parameters is the best way to achieve stack independency and separation, but I'm running into the following issue:
When I try to deploy my VPC stack for example, it throws an error that my Lambda stack is using an invalid S3 bucket name. The Lambda stack is supposed to get the bucket name after the S3 stack is deployed, where the SSM bucket name parameter will be created, but It doesn't seem to let me just deploy the stacks one by one in the correct order, as when I try to deploy or synth a single stack it evaluates all stacks.
One way of resolving this I think would be chaining the stacks using the add_dependency Stack method, but that will link them in a manner I'm trying to avoid, as I'd like to be able to change stacks and deploy them without interacting with other stacks at all.
A different "solution" would be manually adding temporary SSM parameters of the same name to avoid the error before the correct parameters are created and assigned, but that feels like a bad way to go about it as it wont scale well and is prone to errors.
If my method is entirely wrong, please correct me on how to have automatically deployable stacks that are independent of each other while still referencing each other, cause I'm not able to find an answer to this specific question.

This isn't an answer to your question, but as a general rule, pretending that your stacks don't depend on each other when in fact they do depend on each other will bite you at some point. I would suggest modeling the actual reality with your CDK code - those inter-stack dependencies will not result in any unnecessary changes.

@gshpychka I've just been told that making them as independent as possible is good practice, is that not the case? I thought the concept of having one stack add parameters to SSM that another stack uses was a neat way to solve dependency issues from my limited knowldege.

My point was that you're not actually making them independent, because in reality they still need / depend on each other. You're just telling CDK that they're independent.
What using SSM params gets you is the ability to update these references. You could pass the SSM params between the stacks at least to achieve the same thing while still making sure CDK knows that these stacks depend on each other.
